# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, java-17

i am getting below error while trying to start my java application. i configured java 17 in intellij and in environment variable. So just wanted to know, what is the possible reason of this error.

Execution failed for task ':DemoApplication.main()'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
> For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
> BUILD FAILED in 3s
> 3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date

Comment: Make sure it compiles properly before trying to run it

Comment: Looks like an error in your program itself. You should also have an error message from the program itself.

Comment: _"Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output."_ Or try looking at the output before this message.